# Automatic rescaling for Qt application on high-dpi Windows platform?

Tags: qt, resolution, dpi

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367355/automatic-rescaling-of-an-application-on-high-dpi-windows-platform) already, but I'm trying to reignite its flame because it received no answer. So the question still stands, is there a way for me to automatically upscale my applications for higher resolution monitors? Or is this feature still unavailable?

Comment: There is support for high DPI displays since Qt 5.4. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367355/automatic-rescaling-of-an-application-on-high-dpi-windows-platform/28598760#28598760

Comment: yes, please check here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html . Take precise look to QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS please.