# Make pyqt4 application adopt to high dpi displays

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've created an application using Python 3.2 and PyQt4. When it runs on a higher resolution monitor like ~1900x1300 pixel densities the widget looks so small.

Is there any way we can make the app to adjust itself according to the DPI of the screen? As suggested [in this qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) I tried configuring the QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO but didn't work out. Please let me know how it can be done?
FYI I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: How have you set the `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO` environment variable?

Comment: Though programmatic means exists for setting the environment variable, I added it manually. Also is there any way we can make the app run DPI unaware in PyQt4?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367355/automatic-rescaling-of-an-application-on-high-dpi-windows-platform I guess for PyQt4 this does not exist.