# How to get device pixel ratio in Qt 4.8 for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt4, hdpi

We have desktop app which uses Qt 4.8. 
We are trying to support different DPI screens like Mac retina, Surface Pro 4 devices.
For Mac we can get the device pixel ratio by just single function call:

```
CGFloat devicePixelRatio = [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor];
```

Is there any utility function available in WinAPI to get device pixel ratio?

thanks.

Comment: What's pixel ratio? I use WinAPI to get the resolution and the physical dimensions of the screen, from there I can calculate the DPI. Is that what you want?

Comment: on MacOSX backingScaleFactor returns 2 for retina display and for non-retina it returns 1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756596(v=vs.85).aspx this shows sample code to get the ratio,  GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX) / 96.0f; but some how its returning 1 only :(

Comment: BTW, right now I am testing this code on win 8.1 installed on bootcamp on macbook pro retina.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution use below code snippet to get the scaling factor,

```
FLOAT dpiX, dpiY;
HDC screen = GetDC(0);
dpiX = static_cast<FLOAT>(GetDeviceCaps(screen, LOGPIXELSX));
dpiY = static_cast<FLOAT>(GetDeviceCaps(screen, LOGPIXELSY));
ReleaseDC(0, screen);

FLOAT scaleFactor = dpiX / 96.0f; // this is same as devicePixelRatio
```

Now need to make your app DPI aware. For that set **Enable DPI Awareness** flag to **Yes** in *Project Settings > Manifest Tool > Input and Output* property page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I calculate the DPI.
Do replace the assertions with actual error checking, as some of those situations actually occur sometimes.

```
#include <QString>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <SetupApi.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

const GUID GUID_CLASS_MONITOR = { 0x4d36e96e, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18 };

// Assumes hEDIDRegKey is valid
bool GetMonitorSizeFromEDID(const HKEY hEDIDRegKey, short& WidthMm, short& HeightMm)
{
    DWORD dwType, AcutalValueNameLength = 128;
    TCHAR valueName[128];

    BYTE EDIDdata[1024];
    DWORD edidsize = sizeof(EDIDdata);

    for (LONG i = 0, retValue = ERROR_SUCCESS; retValue != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS; ++i)
    {
        retValue = RegEnumValue(hEDIDRegKey, i, &valueName[0],
            &AcutalValueNameLength, NULL, &dwType,
            EDIDdata, // buffer
            &edidsize); // buffer size

        if (retValue != ERROR_SUCCESS || QString(valueName) != "EDID")
            continue;

        WidthMm = ((EDIDdata[68] & 0xF0) << 4) + EDIDdata[66];
        HeightMm = ((EDIDdata[68] & 0x0F) << 8) + EDIDdata[67];

        return true; // valid EDID found
    }

    return false; // EDID not found
}

bool GetSizeForDevID(const QString& TargetDevID, short& WidthMm, short& HeightMm)
{
    HDEVINFO devInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevsExA(
        &GUID_CLASS_MONITOR, //class GUID
        NULL, //enumerator
        NULL, //HWND
        DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_PROFILE, // Flags //DIGCF_ALLCLASSES|
        NULL, // device info, create a new one.
        NULL, // machine name, local machine
        NULL);// reserved

    if (NULL == devInfo)
        return false;

    bool success = false;

    for (ULONG i = 0; ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != GetLastError(); ++i)
    {
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData;
        memset(&devInfoData, 0, sizeof(devInfoData));
        devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(devInfoData);

        if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(devInfo, i, &devInfoData))
        {
            CHAR Instance[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
            SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceIdA(devInfo, &devInfoData, Instance, MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN, NULL);

            if (!QString(Instance).contains(TargetDevID))
                continue;

            HKEY hEDIDRegKey = SetupDiOpenDevRegKey(devInfo, &devInfoData,
                DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL, 0, DIREG_DEV, KEY_READ);

            if (!hEDIDRegKey || (hEDIDRegKey == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
                continue;

            success = GetMonitorSizeFromEDID(hEDIDRegKey, WidthMm, HeightMm);
            RegCloseKey(hEDIDRegKey);

            if (success)
                break;
        }
    }
    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(devInfo);
    return success;
}

static bool DisplayDeviceFromHMonitor(HMONITOR hMonitor, DISPLAY_DEVICE& ddMonOut)
{
    MONITORINFOEX mi;
    mi.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
    GetMonitorInfoA(hMonitor, &mi);

    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
    dd.cb = sizeof(dd);

    for (DWORD devIdx = 0; EnumDisplayDevicesA(nullptr, devIdx, &dd, 0); ++devIdx)
    {
        if (QString(dd.DeviceName) != QString(mi.szDevice))
            continue;

        DISPLAY_DEVICE ddMon;
        memset(&ddMon, 0, sizeof(ddMon));
        ddMon.cb = sizeof(ddMon);
        if (EnumDisplayDevicesA(dd.DeviceName, 0, &ddMon, 0))
        {
            ddMonOut = ddMon;
            return true;
        }

        memset(&dd, 0, sizeof(dd));
        dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
    }

    return false;
}

BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(
    _In_  HMONITOR hMonitor,
    _In_  HDC /*hdcMonitor*/,
    _In_  LPRECT /*lprcMonitor*/,
    _In_  LPARAM context
    )

{
    std::vector<HMONITOR> * monitors = (std::vector<HMONITOR>*)context;
    assert(monitors);
    monitors->push_back(hMonitor);

    return TRUE;
}

uint32_t CSystemMetrics::screenDpi(void* window, const CRect& rect)
{
    // Identify the HMONITOR of interest via the callback MyMonitorEnumProc
    HDC dc = GetWindowDC((HWND)window);
    assert(dc);

    RECT windowRect;
    windowRect.top = rect.top;
    windowRect.left = rect.left;
    windowRect.right = rect.right;
    windowRect.bottom = rect.bottom;

    std::vector<HMONITOR> monitors;
    EnumDisplayMonitors(dc, rect.size().area() > 0 ? (&windowRect) : nullptr, MonitorEnumProc, (LPARAM)&monitors);
    ReleaseDC((HWND)window, dc);

    assert(!monitors.empty());

    DISPLAY_DEVICE ddMon;
    assert(DisplayDeviceFromHMonitor(monitors.front(), ddMon));

    MONITORINFO monitorInfo;
    monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
    assert(GetMonitorInfoA(monitors.front(), &monitorInfo));

    const auto deviceIdSections = QString(ddMon.DeviceID).split("\\");
    assert(deviceIdSections.size() > 1);

    short widthMm, heightMm;
    assert(GetSizeForDevID(deviceIdSections[1], widthMm, heightMm));

    const float hDPI = (monitorInfo.rcMonitor.right - monitorInfo.rcMonitor.left) * 25.4f / widthMm;
    const float vDPI = (monitorInfo.rcMonitor.bottom - monitorInfo.rcMonitor.top) * 25.4f / heightMm;

    const uint32_t dpi = uint32_t(((float)hDPI + (float)vDPI / 2.0f) + 0.5f);

    assert(dpi < 700 && widthMm > 100 && heightMm > 100);

    return dpi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now there's a complicated issue camouflaged in a simple question :-) I cannot really answer that, but merely provide some minor hints:

Firstly, Windows does not have the device-pixel vs. logical-pixel paradigm known from OSX, so your question about the "device pixel ratio" may cause irritation among non-OSX-developers.

For Qt, there have been some substantial changes from versions 4.x to 5.x. In fact, you might actually want to consider "upgrading" to Qt 5.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

To quote from this link:

*"Qt 5.4 introduces experimental support for scaling by by device pixel ratio similar to OS X to the platform plugins for Windows and Unix (XCB)."*

Qt 4 on the other hand offers only those tips for "scalable applications":

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/scalability.html

Related SO question:

[Automatic rescaling of an application on high-dpi Windows platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367355/automatic-rescaling-of-an-application-on-high-dpi-windows-platform)

Comment: Yes upgrading to Qt 5 is perfect solution but it will take much more time than manually scaling up the UI items. I somewhat not agree that windows doesn't have device vs logical pixel paradigm because in there own documentation they have given example code where they are creating a window of size 640x480 but scaling it to system DPI.

Comment: `FLOAT dpiX, dpiY;

HDC screen = GetDC(0);
dpiX = static_cast<FLOAT>(GetDeviceCaps(screen, LOGPIXELSX));
dpiY = static_cast<FLOAT>(GetDeviceCaps(screen, LOGPIXELSY));
ReleaseDC(0, screen);

hWnd = CreateWindow(
         TEXT("DirectWriteApp"),
         TEXT("DirectWrite Demo App"),
         WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
         CW_USEDEFAULT,
         CW_USEDEFAULT,
         static_cast<INT>(dpiX * 640.f / 96.f),
         static_cast<INT>(dpiY * 480.f / 96.f),
         NULL,
         NULL,
         hInstance,
         NULL
         );`

Comment: If you cannot answer the question, then please post it as a comment.

Comment: Looks like I found the problem. Some how app was not getting DPI aware after adding <dpiAware>true</dpiAware> in linker manifest file. Instead this manifest file we just need to turn ON "Enable DPI Awareness" option in project settings > Manifest Tool > Input and Output > Enable DPI Awareness. Many thanks for quick points..

Comment: @Violet Giraffe: I tried commenting instead of answering, but SO reputation policy wouldn't let me...