# QT: Different dpi behavior for different widgets

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have two widget inside of one window. 
First widget is a program main menu. 
Second one open when user presses 'New project' button. 
I have enabled DPI via QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS + setAttribute(UseHighDpiPixmaps). 
I have icons dynamically scaled for second widget when I move app from one monitor (windows dpi 100%) to another monitor (windows dpi 175%). 
But first one (main menu) does not work this way.
It just preserves 2x icons without any respect to DPI. 
I found this by marking 2x icons. 
Also I was not able to reproduce this on the toy example.

Could anyone please point me the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367355/automatic-rescaling-of-an-application-on-high-dpi-windows-platform

Comment: I've read this in the past, yes. What concrete place you want to point?