# OpenALPR not work with PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, openalpr

I tried to build a GUI app with PyQt and openalpr, but there are an issue with my code. A simple example:

```
from openalpr import Alpr
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class AnalizePlate(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.alpr = None
        try:
            self.alpr = Alpr("eu", "/etc/openalpr/openalpr.conf", "/usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data")
            if not self.alpr.is_loaded():
                print("Error loading OpenALPR")
        except:
            print "Error"


    def proccess(self):
        self.alpr.set_top_n(7)
        self.alpr.set_default_region("md")

        results = self.alpr.recognize_file("/tmp/1487428945.14.jpg")
        print results

a = AnalizePlate()
a.proccess()
```

Above code works like a charm, but if GUI is involved, strange behavior occurs.

```
from openalpr import Alpr
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class AnalizePlate(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.alpr = None
        try:
            self.alpr = Alpr("eu", "/etc/openalpr/openalpr.conf", "/usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data")
            if not self.alpr.is_loaded():
                print("Error loading OpenALPR")
        except:
            print "Error"


    def proccess(self):
        self.alpr.set_top_n(7)
        self.alpr.set_default_region("md")

        results = self.alpr.recognize_file("/tmp/1487428945.14.jpg")
        print results

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1198, 651)
        self.analize = AnalizePlate()
        self.analize.proccess()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import sip
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's a basic example, but error is still here. Tried to implement `openalpr` code directly to `Window` class with no luck. So basicly, if there is no gui, code works. Using `openALPR version 2.2.4` and `PyQT4`. Also, checked the image, it's there. The same apply when `recognize_array()` is used instead of `recognize file`. Error I got is:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scaleFactor > 1 && image.depth() ==
>   CV_8U) in detectMultiScale, file
>   /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp,
>   line 1081 Caught exception in OpenALPR recognize:
>   /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1081:
>   error: (-215) scaleFactor > 1 && image.depth() == CV_8U in function
>   detectMultiScale
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "analize.py", line 39, in
>   
>       window = Window()   File "analize.py", line 31, in **init**
>       self.analize.proccess()   File "analize.py", line 22, in proccess
>       results = self.alpr.recognize_file("/tmp/1487428945.14.jpg")   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openalpr/openalpr.py", line
>   132, in recognize_file
>       response_obj = json.loads(json_data)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 339, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
>       obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 122 (char 121)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. You should try testing with the latest version of openalpr and its dependencies. FWIW, my setup is: openalpr-2.3.0, opencv-3.2.0, tesseract-3.0.5, python-2.7.10, pyqt-4.12. The openalpr readme claims that opencv-2.4.8 is the minimum requirement. Still, my hunch is that opencv is the most likely culprit, given that the version 2 series is now legacy code and you're not even using the latest release of it (2.4.13).

Comment: After some work absent, i got back in this issue. @ekhumoro noticed opencv version, so did I, but i knew that i have OpenCV 3.1 installed. After investigating installed packages, I remembered that OpenALPR is installed via `apt-get` and it comes with opencv support (version 2.4.9.1). So, installation from source resolved my issue without any code modification. But, the question is, why there is conflict in opencv 2.4.9 and pyqt?

Answer (score 1):

It may be problem of DPI Awareness. you may need to have a look at ***High DPI support*** in Qt on http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html. 
Also if you are willing to update Qt to 5.6 this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/36058813/2135548

Answer (score 1):

I guess signature for new application `app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)` is missing *argc*. Signature for new application is `QApplication(int & argc, char ** argv)` see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html)

Comment: This is completely wrong, and does not answer the question in any way.

Answer (score 1):

We found that with Python multiprocessing when process A launched process B, OpenCV would fail if it was imported in A and called from B, whether or not B imported it again. I'm not familiar with QT but if the window is running in a separate process the same thing may be happening (OpenCV being a dependency of OpenALPR).

If it is, then you'll probably find that leaving AnalizePlate[1] in a separate source file with the `import openalpr` at the top and referencing it from your window code with no `import openalpr` at the top will work fine.

[1]  I think you mean Analyze(US)/Analyse(BR/AU). Analize means something else :-)